# Relation between geodesics on $2-$sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $\mathbb{S}^2$ be the round $2-$sphere and consider $S^1_a$ and $S^2_b$ two geodesics, i.e., two great circles and suppose that they are not the same. Intuitively, I think that there is a rotation matrix by $\theta$, denotes by $R_{\theta}$, such that $R_{\theta}(S^1_a)=S^2_b$, where $\theta$ is the smallest angle between the tangent vectors at the intersection points.

Is it right? Can I consider only rotation matrix to "change" of great circles on $\mathbb{S}^2$? Or need I be carreful with orientation problems?

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two great circles will intersect at two points. You can rotate around the axis determined by those two points in order to move one great circle to the other.